# Добавление определённых элементов к списку кортежей

Tags: python

У меня есть список в котором минимум находится один кортеж с произвольными символами `[('asd',),('qwe',) ...]`. Мне требуется БЕЗ ЦИКЛА добавить к каждому из кортежей внутри списка несколько значений. Чтобы он стал вида `[('asd', 'добавленное значение'),('qwe','добавленное значение'), ...]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без цикла, так без цикла...

```
lst = [('asd',),('qwe',)]
result = list(map(lambda x: x + ('добавленное значение',), lst))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо =)

Comment: Это сработало? Кортеж ведь не изменяемая структура данных

Comment: @Max А здесь исходные кортежи и не меняются, а создаются новые при помощи операции объединения двух кортежей.

Comment: Точно, тогда понятно, спасибо. Интересно, если его добавленные значения будут разными, как тогда справится без цыкла?